# Ajax can not work with Rails3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My form

```
<%= form_tag load_link_path, :remote => true, :html => { :'data-type' => 'html', :id => 'load_link_form' } do %>
<fieldset> 
    <%= url_field_tag(:url) %>
    <div class="validation-error"></div>
    <%= submit_tag %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

My action

```
def load
  format.js 
end
```

My js view(load.js.erb)

```
alert(0);
```

When submit the form, alert isn't firing. The console outputs:

```
Processing by LinksController#load as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Save changes", "url"=>"http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/", "authenticity_token"=>"KWwfZH+sivCrWdlVBUPM0MBRPHzcDhmbB96ckLQ82Dg="}
  Rendered links/load.js.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2822ms (Views: 9.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: I presume the alert isn't firing? Try putting respond_to do |format| ...end around the format.js

Comment: Hi, it can not work when add "respond_to do |format|"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `respond_to` at the top of your controller and then wrapping your format.js call in a `respond_with` block

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def load
    respond_with do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

I'd recommend reading [this article](http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html), it's the best guide to ajax with rails3 imo.

**UPDATE:**

I got it working after making a few small changes:

The default method for an ajax call in rails is "GET" so if you want to do a "POST", you need to include this with `:data-method=>"post"`. I also removed the html hash from your form tag and set the **data-type** to *script*, see below:

```
<%= form_tag load_link_path, :remote => true, :id => 'create_link_form', :data => {:type=>"script", :"method"=>"post"} do %>
```

Also, you need to uncomment the alert from your js.erb file, so change from:

```
//alert(0);
$('#message').val('ok');
```

to:

```
alert(0);
//$('#message').val('ok');
```

Hope this helps, let me know if it doesn't and i'll push my code to github:)

Comment: is it possible for you to upload your code to github, i am happy to clone it and see where it's failing

Comment: It's a Chinese site, which can help user to share something like article、video、doc、link........My question is on this page: http://localhost:3000/posts/new/link , I want to make a ajax test first